# How install grub on a x64 phone?

Tags: boot, root, grub, chroot, android

I tried to mount the boot partition to install grub (from chroot) but I could not.

In the directory where you mount the boot partition there did not appear anything.

What do I do?

PS: I have the asus zenfone 2 rooted with a custom rom and TWRP recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a grub image yourself and either flash it as boot or recovery with `fastboot flash (boot|recovery) $path_to_image`.

To verify your image is working before flashing, you should use `fastboot boot $path_to_image`

You will need to read documentation specific to your device to know how to build the grub image.